# Using nine-patch to scale a background image with a centred icon, and footer text

Tags: android, cordova, nine-patch, phonegap-build

I am attempting to use a nine-patch splash screen with [Phonegap Build](http://build.phonegap.com/) to replace the default Cordova icon.

I have setup my nine-patch images correctly.

When I build the app and run it however, the nine-patch is being ignored, as though Phonegap build is not even using it. My splash image does appear, but it is skewed, and I can even see the nine-patch borders.

I have seen various solutions around the place, but they don't appear to be using Phonegap build, rather Eclipse build which I have no idea about.

About a year ago, **[this case was opened on Phonegap's github](https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/20)** in an attempt to solve this problem, but it was eventually just closed a few months ago without comment whether it was fixed or if there was a solution.

Is a properly scaling nine-patch splash screen possible with Phonegap Build? And if so, how is this done?

Answer (score 0):

In PhoneGap, we have Whole screen as an image ! It doesn't need the 9Patch image. There are different images for different resolutions for Android. And They are located in Assets/res/screen/android/

This is how PhoneGap Build detects it automatically and sets it according to the screen size.

Comment: I understand that there are different images for different resolutions. We are using a fullscreen image also. But if you use nine-patch, it does effect how the image is displayed. Those 4 sizes provided, ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi are just 4 sizes - there are nearly countless resolutions. If your phone is exactly xhdpi, then the xhdpi will look ok, but if your phone is xhdpi + 10px, it will stretch, and not always proportionately, hence the need for nine-patch.

Comment: I see your thought process. But what I am telling you is, PhoneGap Build has got a recognition of those 4 images server side, and it compiles accordingly ! So to imply your thought process, PhoneGap guys would have to change their server side script ! :)

Comment: I appreciate you explaining that, but the Phonegap docs specify to use nine-patch for the splash backgrounds. If I create the images in just the sizes suggested without nine-patch my image is stretched incorrectly. e.g. in portrait mode, the picture is longer, and it looks stupid.